# iOS check server connection and successful download

Tags: iphone, ios5

I'm making an app that downloads data from a plist and uses that data in a tableview.  Is there a way to check whether a connection to a url is successful and then whether the download was successful? Or maybe a tutorial that implements something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must implement this delegate of NSURLConnection

`//send the request
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];`

in the case of connection failure,this method will be executed

`-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSlog(@"no connection");
}`